# How I can add additional path to img src using jquery in a certain div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently have this input for my img tag:

```
  <div id="myDiv">
      <img src="/assets/images/upload/test1.jpg" />
      <img src="/assets/images/upload/test2.jpg" />
      <img src="/assets/images/upload/test3.jpg" />
  </div>
```

How I can use jquery to add image path like `/newfolder/` to all image tags in `myDiv` using jquery?
I found that jquery can alter the image src...for example

```
$('#myDiv img').attr('src','/newfolder/assets/images/upload/test.jpg')
```

Now..how I can continuously find other images in `myDiv` and add pre-path like `/newfolder/` to all image src in `myDiv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var picRoot="/newfolder";

$('#myDiv img').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).attr('src').indexOf(picRoot)!== 0){
        $(this).attr('src', picRoot + $(this).attr('src'));
    }
});
```

Call it, if your content changes.